# Scanning Wifi list on background

Tags: java, android

### Problem

I'm making an app that can detect if current place is a particular place and play the sound if I'm locating in a particular place. So, I'm going to detect the place using wifi names(ssid).

Thus, I want to get ssid list when the app is running on background service. Also, it should always get ssid list  because it plays sound when user reached the place.

### Question

So my question is, How to **always** get ssid list and detect the place on background?

Comment: what about getting both the ssid list and location in the background service?

Comment: @ruben I'm going to detect location if ssid has a specific keyword. For instance, if ssid has 'lib' keyword, my app will regard the location as library.

Comment: So you have a specific list of ssid  by default against which you can match? In that case, search for ssid in regular intervals in the service and match against your list?

Comment: @ruben That's right. But I don't have any experiences of making background services, so can you tell me how much the regular interval length is appropriate? I think it could use a lot of battery if the interval length were too long, but if the length were too short, it couldn't always get location.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should using a service to run a scan task, because of background limitation, my suggestion is foreground service, refer [foreground-services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

Second, about wifi scan feature, on Android, we can get a list of Wi-Fi access points that are visible from the device, but have few limitations apply to the frequency of scan, each background app (All background apps combined for android 9 and higher) can scan one time in a 30-minute period , and  2-minute period for foreground app.
please refer : [wifi-scan-throttling](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-throttling)